# jQuery: snapped scrolling - possible?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm having a scrollable table with fixed header.
Would it be possible to have "snapped scrolling" on the scrollbar - which means that the table rows won't scroll pixel by pixel but snap responding to its row height, for better viewing.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is 'yes' .. you can adjust .scrollTop and make it be anything you want in response to an onscroll event

read about scrollTop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollTop)

read about the scroll event [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/scroll)

Comment: nice - i figured out how to do it - here's my code:

 tBody.scroll(function(valu){
  var nu = Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop()/17)*17;
  $(this).scrollTop(nu);
 });

the problem: the "default" scrolling when moving the scrollbar is intersecting with my new valung, thus causing to have the content around - is there a way to disable this kind of default scrolling?

Comment: sorry saved too early - i meant it is JUMPING around

Comment: If I was doing this, I'd let the table scroll the way it wants but after the button is released I would $().animate() scrolltop up or down to the whole-row position you want

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is have a 0px-wide Dummy DIV—with a scrollbar—set to the same height as the Target DIV—with no scrollbar.

I would then track the scroll-offset of the Dummy DIV for setting the Target DIV's scroll attribute. It would feel fluid, natural, and the most transparent to the user, which is really important for a good experience.