# Vertical scrolling snap jQuery

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I have taken a look at this [jQuery: snapped scrolling - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811034/jquery-snapped-scrolling-possible) and this [Scrollable Panel snap to elements on Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800404/scrollable-panel-snap-to-elements-on-scroll). But they don't really answer the question I have.

I have a divs that's really wide but same height as window. It moves to the left nicely when the user scrolls. But can I get this scroller to snap when the user stops scrolling. 
So the container sits 28px to the left at the beginning and I want it to snap at the start and then every 207px after that depending which snap point the user is closer to.

```
---------------------
|-------------------|-------------------
|                   |                   |
|                   |                   |            
|-------------------|-------------------
---------------------
```

At the minute I am not using jQuery for much except the width of the container.

```
var numOfPosts = jQuery(".blog-post").length;
var div5 = numOfPosts/5;
var gutters = Math.ceil(div5)*10;
var posts = Math.ceil(div5)*197;
var postListWidth = gutters + posts + 9;
var w = jQuery(window).width();
var h = jQuery(window).height();
    if(postListWidth<=w){
        jQuery(".post-list").width(w-28);
    }else{
        jQuery(".post-list").width(postListWidth);
     }
```

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this? I would prefer to know the code so if there's a solution can you explain it? I am learning jQuery but there's loads I don't know about -.-
Thanks very much for any help I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm hoping you mean horizontal scroll snap.  From your diagramm it looks more like that's what you mean.  If that's the case, you could do something similiar to what's demonstrated in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLrQW/3/embedded/result/).  It uses [this scrollstop event plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/) to know when to animate your scroll to the nearest interval.  Using this plugin code (placed after the scrollstop plugin code):

```
(function($) {      
    $.fn.scrollSnap = function(snapInterval) {
        var mousedown = false;

        function nearestInterval(n, iv) {
            return Math.round(n / iv) * iv;
        }

        function snapToInterval() {
            if(mousedown) {
                $(window).one("mouseup", snapToInterval);
            } else {
                var $this = $(this),
                    snapLeft = nearestInterval($this.scrollLeft(), snapInterval);

                $(this).animate({scrollLeft: snapLeft});
            }
        }

        $(window).mousedown(function() { mousedown = true });
        $(window).mouseup(function() { mousedown = false });

        this.each(function() {
            $(this).bind("scrollstop", snapToInterval);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You'll then be able to use this on elements with scrollbars:

```
$("#scrollWrapper").scrollSnap(207);
```

For a prebuilt solution, you might want to check out [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not opposed to using more jQuery try jQuery UI Slider. It has snaping option.
These examples should be helpful.

[Used as Scrollbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll)

[Scroll tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#tabs)

Comment: This could work: set the step size, and then style the slider and handle using CSS accordingly.